# HTML5 and Javascript : Opening and Reading a Local File with File API

Tags: javascript, html, jsni, fileapi

I am using Google Web Toolkit for a project and would like the user to select a text file to open in a text window inside the browser.  Here's the almost working code:

```
 private DialogBox createUploadBox() {
     final DialogBox uploadBox = new DialogBox();
     VerticalPanel vpanel = new VerticalPanel();
     String title = "Select a .gms file to open:";
     final FileUpload upload = new FileUpload();
     uploadBox.setText(title);
     uploadBox.setWidget(vpanel);
     HorizontalPanel buttons = new HorizontalPanel();
     HorizontalPanel errorPane = new HorizontalPanel();
     Button openButton = new Button( "Open", new ClickHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            String filename = upload.getFilename();
            int len = filename.length();
            if (len < 5) {
                Window.alert("Please enter a valid filename.\n\tFormat: <filename>.gms");
            } else if (!filename.substring(len-4).toLowerCase().equals(".gms")) {
                Window.alert(filename.substring(len-4) + " is not valid.\n\tOnly files of type .gms are allowed.");
            } else {
                Window.alert(getFileText(filename));
            }
        }
        private native String getFileText(String filename) /*-{
            // Check for the various File API support.
            if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
                // Great success! All the File APIs are supported.
                var reader = new FileReader();
                var file = File(filename);
                str = reader.readAsText(file);
                return str;
            } else {
                alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
                return;
            }
        }-*/;
     });
     Button cancelButton = new Button( "Cancel", 
             new ClickHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            uploadBox.hide();               
        }
     });
     buttons.add(openButton);
     buttons.add(cancelButton);
     vpanel.add(upload);
     vpanel.add(buttons);
     vpanel.add(errorPane);
     uploadBox.setAnimationEnabled(true);
     uploadBox.setGlassEnabled(true);
     uploadBox.center();
     return uploadBox;
 }
```

Whenever I try to actually use this function in my program, I get:

**(NS_ERROR_DOM_SECURITY_ERR): Security error**

I'm certain it is being cased by:

```
var file = new File(filename, null);
```

Disclaimer: I'm not a Javascript programmer by any stretch, please feel free to point out any obvious mistakes I'm making here.

Comment: re: the edits - window/$wnd is probably the only point that is gwt-specific. That, and how to pass in the InputElement instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `window`, you should almost always use `$wnd`. See https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI#writing for more details about JSNI.

It could also be worthwhile to add a `debugger` statement while using something like Firebug, or Chrome's Inspector. This statement will stop the JS code in the debugger as if you had put a breakpoint there, are allow you to debug in Javascript, stepping one line at a time to see exactly what went wrong.

And finally, are you sure the file you are reading is permitted by the browser? From http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/#dfn-SecurityError, that error could be occurring because the browser has not been permitted access to the file. Instead of passing in the String, you might pass in the `<input type='file' />` the user is interacting with, and get the file they selected from there.

---

Update (sorry for the delay, apparently the earlier update I made got thrown away, took me a bit to rewrite it):

Couple of bad assumptions being made in the original code. Most of my reading is from http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/, plus a bit of experimenting.

- First, that you can get a real path from the `<input type='file' />` field, coupled with
- that you can read arbitrary files from the user file system just by path, and finally
- that the `FileReader` API is synchronous.

For security reasons, most browsers do not give real paths when you read the filename - check the string you get from `upload.getFilename()` in several browsers to see what it gives - not enough to load the file. Second issue is also a security thing - very little good can come of allowing reading from the filesystem just using a string to specify the file to read.

For these first two reasons, you instead need to ask the `input` for the files it is working on. Browsers that support the FileReader API allow access to this by reading the `files` property of the input element. Two easy ways to get this - working with the NativeElement.getEventTarget() in jsni, or just working with FileUpload.getElement(). Keep in mind that this `files` property holds multiple items by default, so in a case like yours, just read the zeroth element.

```
private native void loadContents(NativeEvent evt) /*-{
    if ($wnd.File && $wnd.FileReader && $wnd.FileList && $wnd.Blob) {
        // Great success! All the File APIs are supported.
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsText(evt.target.files[0]);
//...
```

or

```
private native void loadContents(Element elt) /*-{
    if ($wnd.File && $wnd.FileReader && $wnd.FileList && $wnd.Blob) {
        // Great success! All the File APIs are supported.
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsText(elt.files[0]);
//...
```

For the final piece, the `FileReader` api is asynchronous - you don't get the full contents of the file right away, but need to wait until the `onloadend` callback is invoked (again, from http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/). These files can be big enough that you wouldn't want the app to block while it reads, so apparently the spec assumes this as the default.

This is why I ended up making a new `void loadContents` methods, instead of keeping the code in your `onClick` method - this method is invoked when the field's `ChangeEvent` goes off, to start reading in the file, though this could be written some other way.

```
// fields to hold current state
private String fileName;
private String contents;
public void setContents(String contents) {
  this.contents = contents;
}

// helper method to read contents asynchronously 
private native void loadContents(NativeEvent evt) /*-{;
    if ($wnd.File && $wnd.FileReader && $wnd.FileList && $wnd.Blob) {
        var that = this;
        // Great success! All the File APIs are supported.
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsText(evt.target.files[0]);
        reader.onloadend = function(event) {
            that.@com.sencha.gxt.examples.test.client.Test::setContents(Ljava/lang/String;)(event.target.result);
        };
    } else {
        $wnd.alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
    }
}-*/;

// original createUploadBox
private DialogBox createUploadBox() {
  final DialogBox uploadBox = new DialogBox();
  VerticalPanel vpanel = new VerticalPanel();
  String title = "Select a .gms file to open:";
  final FileUpload upload = new FileUpload();
  upload.addChangeHandler(new ChangeHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onChange(ChangeEvent event) {
      loadContents(event.getNativeEvent());
      fileName = upload.getFilename();
    }
  });
  // continue setup
```

The 'Ok' button then reads from the fields. It would probably be wise to check that contents is non null in the `ClickHandler`, and perhaps even null it out when the `FileUpload`'s `ChangeEvent` goes off.

Comment: Sorry, but like I said before, I'm not a javascript programmer.  Could you give a concrete example of using that <input type='file'/> bit?

Comment: I think you are correct about the browser not allowing access to the file.  Do I need to submit the file in a form?

Comment: Not submit, but let the user browse to a file, then look at their selection. Take a look at http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/#toc-reading-files - you'll add a handler for ChangeEvent to the FileUpload widget - user clicks browse, selects something, and you'll be able to read the NativeEvent out like they do in handleFileSelect. You might need a custom widget other than FileUpload, its been a while since I played with this. Update the Q with an almost-working code sample, and I'll see if I can follow up more.

Comment: Colin - what you are saying kind of makes sense to me.  I'm missing some fundamentals, definitely.  I've updated my question with the entire code block.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just put an update with a mostly working impl, let me know if you have any q's.

Comment: One question: why the `var that = this;` reassignment?  I can think of one reason myself, but I just want to hear it from someone who knows what they are doing :)

Comment: The `that=this` is for the `onloadend` callback - `this` isn't really the same in JS as it is in Java, so you need to account for the fact that in that callback, `this` will mean whatever the function is being invoked on. A quick example suggests it will the the `FileReader`, but in many cases callbacks are invoked with `window` (in gwt, `$wnd`) as the `this`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you can only use `new File(name)` when writing extensions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extensions/Using_the_DOM_File_API_in_chrome_code