# How can I load a local file using jQuery? (with file://)

Tags: jquery

Is there any way to load data from a data file (eg a JSON .js file) using jQuery?

eg:

```
$.get("file:///C:/objectData.js", function() { alert('Load was performed.'); });
```

At the moment, instead of doing a simple HTTP GET, JQuery appears to be trying to do an OPTIONS request on it, which fails on a file:// URI.  I just want to load the data in so that the site can be used in an offline environment (without a web server installed).

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408707/jquery-read-text-file-from-file-system

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GET requires an HTTP connection, so without a local web servber it won't work. While you can [open and read a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132018/html5-and-javascript-opening-and-reading-a-local-file-with-file-api) using HTML5, you can't load a JavaScript resource that way.

If the page is loaded locally, you'd usually load the JS using a script tag.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/objectData.js'></script>
```

The only way around this may be in this answer: [Is it possible to load in a local version of a JavaScript file instead of the server version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516359/is-it-possible-to-load-in-a-local-version-of-a-javascript-file-instead-of-the-se)

or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10452381/load-local-css-and-javascript-files-when-developing-live-when-pushed-to-server) (both require making a local pseudo-server) :

Answer (score 4):

I hope it is possible. I'd tried it. the Html code and text files resides in the same folder.

Here is jQuery part.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("select").change(function()
    {


        file_name = $("select").val();
        $('#span_result').load(file_name);
    });
});
```

The Html code is

```
<select class="sel"  name="files">
    <option  value="">Select a file</option>
    <option  value="file.txt">file.txt</option>
    <option  value="file2.txt">file2.txt</option>
    <option  value="jQuery_file.html">jQuery_file.html</option>
    </select><br>
    <p>Contents of the file will be displayed below</p>
    <div id="span_result"></div>
```

Itworked for me in firefox. Sorry if it failed with you.

Comment: On Chrome, this fails on file:// - "Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource." As expected from the docs. http://api.jquery.com/load/ "Load data from the server"

Comment: Because you're serving it locally (hence file://). You need to do this from a web server.