# Is there any way to read file in jquery or javascript with file:// protocol?

Tags: javascript, jquery, same-origin-policy

I know few firefox version allow to read file without `http` or `https`, Is there any way to read file in jquery or javascript with `file://` protocol ? I am developing static application, which works well with web server, if I am able to do something similar to the job of below `Jquery.ajax` function with protocol being `file://` I will be very happy

**This works well if I have web server (`http/https`) what can be done for `file://` ?**

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost/something/somefile.txt",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data){ dothis(data); }
       });
```

What I will do if I don't have web server ? I know due to [SOP](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDAQFjAEahUKEwji7a6z0uTIAhWCFJQKHUvpAU4&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FSame-origin_policy&usg=AFQjCNE6A0d-w9WfIkW8wsrfucTNFgW9Rw&sig2=sA9QFud7T8P3yAlnV-hRcQ&bvm=bv.106130839,d.dGo) (Same origin policy) modern browsers doesn't allow. Is there any alternate method to do the similar job so that which does support all browser with protocol being `file://` ?

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507677/how-can-i-load-a-local-file-using-jquery-with-file

Answer (score 0):

If you just read files, consider setting up a one-click HTTP server on your computer.

For example I use [Web Server for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb/).

Comment: What if OS is not Windows ?

Answer (score 0):

You may like to use **FileSystem API** which comes in html5. This has several features which i guess you are looking for. what you can do with this api are:

1. Requesting a file system
2. Requesting storage quota
3. Working with files
4. Creating a file
5. Reading a file by name
6. Writing to a file
7. Appending data to a file
8. Duplicating user-selected files
9. Removing a file
10. Working with directories
11. Creating directories
12. Subdirectories
13. Reading a directory's contents
14. Removing a directory
15. Copying, renaming, and moving
16. filesystem: URLs

The above points are taken from [html5rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/). Other than this you can look at [**MDN** for filesystem api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_API).

---

### Note:

> In April 2014, it was announced on *public-webapps* that the **Filesystem API** spec is not being considered by other browsers. **For now, the API is Chrome-specific** and it's unlikely to be implemented by other browsers and is **no longer being standardized with the W3C**.