# Cannot load static text from local file into js variable with jQuery $.GET

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get

I'm developing Google Chrome extension. I have a **static** `countryList.js` file which is placed **locally** in the same folder with another file with the code below. I just want to load `countryList.js` content into js variable of the second file, but my code doesn't work, though it works if `countryList.js` is placed on a remote server. What am I doing wrong? I can not place it on the server because it is forbidden for Chrome extensions.

```
 var countryList = $.get("countryList.js" + localStorage.uid + "&ver=" + localStorage.version, function () {
   callback()
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate: 
[How can I load a local file using jQuery? (with file://)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507677/how-can-i-load-a-local-file-using-jquery-with-file)

GET requires an HTTP connection, so without a local web server it won't work. While you can open and read a file using HTML5, you can't load a JavaScript resource that way.

If the page is loaded locally, you'd usually load the JS using a script tag.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/objectData.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you missing a "?" after countryList.js in your get url?